# MySQL Lottery Search

Tags: mysql, search

I'm looking for a MySQL only solution to searching a list of lottery tickets against numbers drawn.

I have rows of tickets with each of four numbers in their own columns: ball1, ball2, ball3, ball4.
These will not necessarily be in ascending numerical order.

The query should just return the row for further PHP processing.

I could go through all results in PHP, but I'm looking for something more efficient.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing, as yet, as the only solution I can think of immediately would be a massive MySQL search comparing all ball columns to all result numbers... eg `WHERE (ball1=[result1] OR ball1=[result2] OR ball1=[result3]...`
I was hoping for something a little more elegant

Comment: Are you stuck with this schema?  A table of `(drawId, ballValue)` (and optionally also `ballNumber` if retaining that information is desired) would be much easier to work with.

Comment: Only the tickets are stored, the result is entered manually. But yes, I'm stuck with this as it is a system already in place - just needing an automatic checker". No need to store which ball number it was - just to match 4 ticket numbers to 4 result numbers in any order.

Comment: SELECT ball1 ball FROM mytable UNION SELECT ball2 etc

Comment: Sorry Strawberry, can you explain a bit more what you mean? Not getting it...

Comment: How do you plan to draw a ticket? Randomly from each of these 4 columns?

Comment: The lottery draw will have been made separately which has the winning numbers - these then must be matched to find any winning tickets from the database.

Comment: @chrismcb The problem is that your data is not normalised. For some reason you cannot modify your table structure, so the solution is to construct a 'virtual' table (sorry, correct word's left my head) and then perform your query against that.

Comment: I believe that you have 4 numbers with you and you have to extract a ticket with all balls (ball1 , ball2, ball3,ball4) of same number. and the order of balls is not the same

Comment: Did you get this as homework before you were taught about joins?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this example.

Say we want to match all results that have any combination of at least three out of these four balls (2,4,5,10)

We could do that like this...

```
SELECT * FROM lottery;
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
| id | ball1 | ball2 | ball3 | ball4 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+
|  1 |     2 |     5 |    10 |     4 |
|  2 |     5 |     9 |     4 |     1 |
|  3 |     3 |     6 |     4 |     9 |
|  4 |     4 |     8 |     2 |     3 |
|  5 |     8 |     9 |     4 |    10 |
|  6 |     9 |     2 |     1 |     3 |
|  7 |     2 |     3 |     7 |     8 |
|  8 |     3 |     8 |     2 |     6 |
|  9 |     2 |     5 |     1 |    10 |
| 10 |     3 |     2 |     9 |     5 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+-------+

SELECT id
     , GROUP_CONCAT(ball ORDER BY ball) balls
  FROM 
     ( SELECT id,ball1 ball FROM lottery
       UNION
       SELECT id,ball2 ball FROM lottery
       UNION
       SELECT id,ball3 ball FROM lottery
       UNION
       SELECT id,ball4 ball FROM lottery
     ) x
 WHERE ball IN (2,5,10,4)
 GROUP 
    BY id 
HAVING COUNT(*) >= 3;

+----+----------+
| id | balls    |
+----+----------+
|  1 | 2,4,5,10 |
|  9 | 2,5,10   |
+----+----------+
```

Comment: Excellent @Strawberry - exactly the elegant solution I was after - and all in MySQL!